# Error: "Invalid column name", but columns have already been created

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have created a web project, but when I try to insert values into my local database I get the following error:

> Error : Invalid column name ''22 478 295 290''. Invalid column name ''Oreki''. Invalid column name ''Redgrave''. Invalid column name ''Female''. Invalid column name ''Sample@gmail.com''. Invalid column name ''1234''. Invalid column name ''12, 1 2017''. Invalid column name ''18:41:44:529''.

This is my SQL-Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account] (
[ID]           VARCHAR(50)          NOT NULL,
[Firstname]    VARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
[Lastname]     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[Gender]       VARCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
[Email]        VARCHAR(50)            NOT NULL,
[Password]     VARCHAR(50)            NOT NULL,
[DateRegister] VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
[TimeRegister] VARCHAR (25)    NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Account] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
```

);

This is my ASP.Net C# code:

```
    try
    {
        SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Oreki Illustration\\Documents\\NowTips.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        SqlCommand Say = new SqlCommand();
        DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;

        string GetStringDate = Date.Month.ToString() + ", " + Date.Day.ToString() + " " + Date.Year.ToString();
        string GetStringTime = Date.Hour.ToString() + ":" + Date.Minute.ToString() + ":" + Date.Second.ToString() + ":" + Date.Millisecond.ToString();

        Connect.Open();
        Say.Connection = Connect;
        Say.CommandText = "Insert into Account values (['" + GetID + "'], ['" + Firstname.Text + "'], ['" + Lastname.Text + "'], ['" + Gender.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'], ['" + Email.Text + "'], ['" + RePassword.Text + "'], ['" + GetStringDate + "'], ['" + GetStringTime + "'])";
        Say.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Connect.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception Message)
    {
        form1.InnerHtml = "Error : " + Message.Message;
    }


public string GetID
{
    get
    {
        string A = "", B = "", C = "", D = "";

        Random RandomID = new Random();

        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) A = RandomID.Next(1000).ToString();
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) B = RandomID.Next(1000).ToString();
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) C = RandomID.Next(1000).ToString();
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) D = RandomID.Next(1000).ToString();

        return A + " " + B + " " + C + " " + D;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: My sql or SQL Server? In title, do you mean Your SQL db or your "MySQL" DB

Comment: Local SQL Query

Comment: No, I'm asking about which SQL product you are using? Anyway i know the Answer its SQL Server. DON'T tag the products that you are not used.

Comment: Remove the square brackets around the VALUES. Beyond this your code is vulnerable to Sql Injection. **Learn As Soon As Possible how to avoid it** (Hint: search for Parameterized queries)

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Community SQL Server

Comment: okay i got it sir

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as below with parameters,

```
 cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Account values
                ([@GetID, @Firstname, @Lastname, @Gender, @Email, @RePassword, @GetStringDate, @GetStringTime)";
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GetID", GetID);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", Firstname.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", Lastname.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender.SelectedValue.ToString());
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RePassword", RePassword.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GetStringDate", GetStringDate);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GetStringTime", GetStringTime);
```

---

you are not doing thing proper way ,

1. passing parameter like this lead you to sql injection
2. to avoid it make use of Sql parameter
3. make use of `using` for connection, so it will get automatically dispose

Below is example how you can do it , Whole point here is make use of Parameter not plain query like you did right now

```
string commandText = "UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics "
        + "WHERE CustomerID = @ID;";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

        // Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics.
        // SQL Server will implicitly convert strings into XML.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @OrekiRedgrave - try the way i suggested saves you from errors in future

Comment: @OrekiRedgrave Marking the Answer as `solution` is the best way to say thanks.